# My rigid body simulation was working fine until yesterday, and it now will not bake at all

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

For the last four months I've been making an animated movie as a school project. In one scene I had a bunch of transistors move out of the way of something that was falling using a rigid body sim, but they have since stopped and I have found no way to fix them.

This is a pared back version of my blender file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1012au64fmvsl3n/board%20copy.blend?dl=0

Comment: i just can assume you deleted a lot here so you have to upload just a smaller version...but unfortunately you deleted also the rigid body world collection...by this this could never have worked. So maybe upload the "full" file?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @Chris Perhaps that is the problem. In the full file no such collection exists. Not sure how, but I may have deleted it by accident. It it possible to recover, or create a new one?

Comment: The RIgid Body World collection is a virtual collection, it exists by default and it doesn't need to exist in the Outliner. I may be wrong but I suspect a bug, it looks like it can happen...

Comment: @moonboots: uhm...i just made this very easy test: from a new file with default cube, add rigid body to him, start animation - falls. Now delete rigid collection here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEMLh.png -> start animation -> nothing falls. Yes, the collection is not visible in "normal" outliner, but it has to be in the settings - i think - and in the uploaded file it wasn't there.

Comment: @DJMoffinz: tbh i have no idea how to create that collection and what should be in there. I just deleted it now to test it - but even with removing rigid body world and adding again - the collection didn't come back. Maybe some more rigid body experienced guys know that - my knowledge is limited here. You can maybe try to import it from another blend file - but that's just a shot in the dark...

Comment: oh ok yes he may have deleted it  ;)  but it should work if he select the collection where the objects currently are

Comment: even that i tried - didn't work

Comment: because it's bugged, try to disable and reactivate the object visibility in the Outliner (still doesn't work with his file though)

Comment: no, i tried with my 1 cube file ;) - if i delete that collection - it's over...or at least: i have no idea how to repair that

Comment: mmh I've tried from scratch and if you delete Rigid Body World but choose the collection where the objects are, it works, sometimes it seems to bug but if you deactivate and reactivate the collection it works. I think some bugs happen with rigid bodies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140819/discussion-between-moonboots-and-chris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was select the objects that were being simulated and add them to a new collection, then select that collection in the rigid body world collection select box. Kudos to @moonboots for giving me the idea.